# как задать return в цикле после всех итераций цикла for в JS?

Tags: javascript, циклы, for, return

нужно ловить последнюю итерацию и ей задавать? Тогда как задать return после последней итерации?

---

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.bad_iin.length; i++) { 
  if (value == this.bad_iin[i]) { 
    return false; 
  } 
} 
super.iin = value;
```

мне нужно если цикл не вернет фолс - исполнить это присвоение.

`value` это параметр сетера, цикл внутри сетера

Comment: Пример кода в студию

Comment: Сделать `return` после цикла?

Comment: а задать `return` после цикла? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По завершении цикла будет выполняться следующий за ним код. Туда и добавляйте return. Если вам надо вернуть значение, которое существует только в блоке цикла, то объявите внешнюю относительно цикла переменную или воспользуйтесь var внутри блока цикла.

Циклы значения не возвращают. Return будет действовать на окружающую цикл функцию. Нельзя вернуть несколько раз.

Проверка массива на соответствие каждого элемента называется `every():`

```
super.iin = this.bad_iin.every(i => i == value) ? value : false;
```

super.iin будет иметь значение false если хотя бы один элемент массива не пройдет проверку. Если нужно другое значение (по умолчанию), то задайте его: это вместо слова false в самом конце выражения.

Comment: у меня на каждой итерации идет проверка элементов массива, условие возвращает фолс. Мне нужно если не будет ни 1 фолс, возвратить тру. Если я нипишу ретерн тру сразу после цикла, и в цикл вернет мне фолс - получится сначала фолс, потом тру.

Comment: Столько слов... Добавьте код.

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < this.bad_iin.length; i++) {
      if (value == this.bad_iin[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    super.iin = value;

мне нужно если цикл не вернет фолс - исполнить это присвоение.

Comment: value это что? Где она объявлена? что содержит?

Comment: value это параметр сетера, цикл внутри сетера,

Comment: Я написал вам код, смотрите.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: Так помог хоть?

Answer (score 1):

```
let found = false;
for (let i = 0; i < this.bad_iin.length; i++) { 
  if (value == this.bad_iin[i]) { 
    found = true; 
    break;
  } 
} 
if (!found) {
  super.iin = value;
}
```

Comment: я же ему сразу предложил вынести во внешнюю переменную. Но с break вместо return видно надо было сразу))) И, может, тогда и вопрос отредактируешь, а то не понятно к чему такие ответы... (я не умею))))

Comment: Да))) намного понятней его вопрос не стал)))